# How to make sed print to the end of line from socat

Tags: macos, bash, sed, socat

I have a server which sends data in a UDP Broadcast on port 10552. The data is 7 numbers separated by commas as so.

```
5.351204,0.001968,-0.000473,-0.999222,0.000451,0.001455,1.084310
```

I fetch this data with

```
socat -u udp-recv:10552,reuseaddr -
```

I want to change the format of this data, so I pipe it into sed. I don't care about the first number, so I remove it with

```
s/[^,]*,//;
```

I add spaces after the commas with

```
s/,/, /g
```

I then add an open parenthesis to the beginning of each line with

```
 s/^/(/
```

Finally, I attempt to add a close parenthesis to the end of each line with

```
s/$/)/
```

The final command ends up being

```
socat -u udp-recv:10552,reuseaddr - | sed 's/[^,]*,//;s/,/, /g;s/^/(/;s/$/)/'
```

Everything works as expected, except the final close parenthesis ends up on the beginning of each line, so it looks like

```
)0.051727, -0.595779, -0.794678, 0.082047, 0.644327, -0.027242
```

Removing the last bit of the command for

```
socat -u udp-recv:10552,reuseaddr - | sed 's/[^,]*,//;s/,/, /g;s/^/(/;'
```

results in

```
(0.079330, -0.608597, -0.786194, 0.092438, 0.657444, -0.031528
```

I have tried replacing appending the end of the line with awk, tr, and also GNU sed, but everything seems to overflow the line or something.

I am on OS X 10.10.3 with the builtin Bash 3.2. Is there anything else I can try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

socat is returning data with `\r\n` line endings. Change

```
s/$/)/
```

to

```
s/\r$/)/
```

That may or may not work with the OSX sed

Comment: That was it! Thanks! OS X sed doesn't like the carriage return, but you can either use GNU sed or preface the command with a $. 

`sed $'s/\r$/)/'`

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to explicitly removing the CR, is to tell `socat` that the lines are CR NL terminated:

```
 socat -u udp-recv:10552,reuseaddr,crnl - | sed 's/[^,]*,//;s/,/, /g;s/^/(/;s/$/)/'
```